# Narrow down sql resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this sql command :

```
SELECT RecordedBy as 'Recorded By', COUNT(*) Total 
FROM mytable 
WHERE 
StartedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '00:01AM')
AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '11:59PM')
group by RecordedBy order by Total desc
```

What I would like to accomplish is to refine the results of this query even more by embedding this sql in another one **without changing the original sql**.

For example I would like to narrow down the original sql by the RecordedBy clause: What I though to do was this:

```
select * from mytable in
(
    SELECT RecordedBy as 'Recorded By', COUNT(*) Total  FROM mytable  
    WHERE  StartedDate BETWEEN 
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'00:01AM')
    AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'11:59PM') 
    group by RecordedBy order by Total desc
)
```

But of course this results in syntax error. 
Can anyone think of something that I am missing right now?

Comment: What is the requirement/refining in the outer select? You can't write an order by clause in inner query.

Comment: refine the original sql (SELECT RecordedBy as 'Recorded By', COUNT(*) Total  F....)

Comment: You also can't reference a subquery by referencing the original tablename, like that. Just do `select * from ( SUBQUERY HERE )` when you've fixed the other syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT RecordedBy as 'Recorded By', 
         COUNT(*) Total
  FROM mytable  
  WHERE  StartedDate 
         BETWEEN 
          DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'00:01AM')  
          AND 
          DATEADD(day,  DATEDIFF(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '11:59PM')  
) as TAB
group by TAB.RecordedBy 
order by TAB.Total desc
```

Comment: i get this error `Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```
select * from 
(
    SELECT RecordedBy as 'Recorded By', COUNT(*) Total  FROM mytable  
    WHERE  StartedDate BETWEEN 
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'00:01AM')
    AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'11:59PM') 
    group by RecordedBy order by Total desc
) mytable
```

Try it.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy did u execute the query in view or in just a normal query window?

Comment: for this to work, i must take the `order by` clause from the inner sql to the outer one. If i leave it as you typed it i get this error `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
`

Comment: you are right. order by didn't work in inside query. anyway that might not disturb your result if you keep it outside.